# I am tring to create "Sinking ships" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, 2d-games

So far I am tring to make functions for placing ships on board and I have some problems with function for checking is some field available. My basic idea is to have one method which will be called on button click:

```
$("#dodaj1x1").click(function(){
        var raspolozivo=parseInt($("#raspolozivo1x1").text());
        if(raspolozivo>0){

            generisi1x1();//call for function that generate random field

            var novoRaspolozivo= raspolozivo-1;
            $("#raspolozivo1x1").html(novoRaspolozivo);
        }
        else{
            alert("Rasporedjeni svi raspolozivi brodovi ovog tipa!");
        }
    });
```

and it will call function to generate random field:

```
function generisi1x1(){
            var minR = 0;
            var maxR = 9;
            var minK = 0;
            var maxK = 9;
            randRed=Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxR - minR + 1)) + minR;
            randKol=Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxK - minK + 1)) + minK;
            proveri1x1(randRed,randKol);//call to function to check is field available
    }
```

than function generisi1x1() calls function that checks is that field available:

```
function proveri1x1(randRed,randKol){
        for(i=randRed-1;i<randRed+2;i++){
            for(j=randKol-1;j<randKol+2;j++){
                if($(".red"+i+".kolona"+j+"").hasClass('deoBroda')){
                    alert("red:"+" "+i+" kolona:"+j);
                    generisi1x1();
                }
                else { postavi1x1(randRed,randKol);}
            }
        }
    }
```

And my problem is that sometimes this work great(at least it looks that work great,maybe pure luck), and sometimes it generate only 3 ships 1x1(there should be 4) , sometimes it show me message about problem and generate 5 ships(4 on right places, 1 on bad) etc.

Printscreen of bad case: [Added ship 1x1 on position 5,3 right next to ship 4x1](http://prntscr.com/4vxr06)

Here is live demo of entire code: [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrinja/dLc96sbh/)

So far I made available to insert ships 4x1 and 1x1, and doing check only for 1x1, plan is to do the same for all ships, any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find it easier to understand if `proveri1x1()` performs the checks and returns `true` or `false`, and `generisi1x1()` performs the `postavi1x1()` action;

```
function generisi1x1() {
    var minR = 0, maxR = 9, minK = 0, maxK = 9;
    randRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxR - minR + 1)) + minR;
    randKol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxK - minK + 1)) + minK;
    if(proveri1x1(randRed, randKol)) { //call to function to check is field available
        postavi1x1(randRed,randKol);//set
    } else {
        generisi1x1();//try again
    }
}

function proveri1x1(randRed, randKol) {
    for(var i=randRed-1; i<randRed+2; i++) {
        for(var j=randKol-1; j<randKol+2; j++) {
            if($(".red" + i + ".kolona" + j).hasClass('deoBroda')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;//<<<< note the position of this return statement
}
```

Comment: @user3294091, Further to my answer, you can reduce the volume of code and make it much easier to define new ship types like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/c0u19o7z/11/). Note - changes to HTML and javascript but not CSS.